# Alternatives to boost::scoped_ptr in C++ 11

Tags: c++, boost

We've just upgraded our compiler to VC++ 2013 which has support for C++ 11. Previously we've been using shared_ptr and scoped_ptr classes from Boost, but since that is all we've been using from Boost, we're looking to remove that dependency.

As far as I can tell, std::shared_ptrs are a drop-in replacement for boost::shared_ptrs, so that's (hopefully) easy.

However, what is the best replacement for Boost scoped_ptrs (if there is one)? Would it be unique_ptr?

(To be honest, even though I wrote the code, it was about 10 years ago, and I've forgotten what the purpose of using scoped_ptrs was... Maybe I was just "playing" with Boost, but as far as I can see a plain pointer would probably do in the cases I've examined).

Comment: Yes, `unique_ptr` would be the replacement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, `scoped_ptr` can and should be replaced with `unique_ptr`. They represent the same idea (unique ownership), but `unique_ptr` does it better, and allows transfer of ownership via move semantics. (`scoped_ptr` didn't because it wasn't possible in C++98)

Comment: It is worth noting that `const std::unique_ptr<T>` is an even more precise replacement of `scoped_ptr`, because the `const` disallows moving from that `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Sure, you could say that. But a `unique_ptr` only allows moving if `T` is movable, and obviously, for C++98 code, that was never the case. `scoped_ptr`'s behavior was never defined for movable types, because movable types did not exist, so I don't really see one behavior as a "more precise replacement" than the other. (However, it is always good to make stuff `const` if you can)

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I'm misunderstanding you. Surely, `unique_ptr<T>` can be moved from regardless of `T`? [See live code example.](http://ideone.com/5APgFI)

Comment: But yeah, it's not as black and white as I was imagining. `scoped_ptr` does indeed not allow moving, it is not a question of that being undefined. It does, however, allow swapping, which wouldn't work with a `const unique_ptr`. So, maybe I could have said "Beware when you replace a `scoped_ptr` with a `unique_ptr`. You might want a `const unique_ptr` where you formerly were satisfied with either a non-`const` `scoped_ptr` or a `const scoped_ptr`". After all, `unique_ptr` *is* more liberal than `scoped_ptr`, and if you want your new code to be as strict, adding `const` might be the proper way.

Comment: @MagnusHoff er, yeah, you're right of course. Sorry, complete brainfart. Yes, you can move to/from a `unique_ptr` regardless of the object type being stored in it.